# Java Servlets: Performance

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am working on a web application in Java which gets data from servlets via AJAX calls.

This application features several page elements which get new data from the server at fairly rapid intervals.

With a lot of users, the demand on the server has a potential to get fairly high, so I am curious:

**Which approach offers the best performance:**

Many servlets (one for each type of data request)?

**Or:**

a single servlet that can handle all of the requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no performance reason to have more than one servlet. In a web application, only a single instance of a servlet class is instantitated, no matter how many requests. Requests are not serialized, they are handled concurrently, hence the need for your servlet to be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks, I was never quite clear about what exactly happened at the low level for servlets.

Answer (score 2):

The [struts framework](http://struts.apache.org/) uses one servlet for everything in your app.  Your stuff plugs into that one servlet.  If it works for them, it will probably work for you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason to have multiple services is that if you need to expand to multiple servers to handle the load in the future, it is easier to move a seperate service to it's own server than to do it "behind the scenes" if everything is comming out of one service.

That being said, there is extra maintinence overhead if you have multiple servlets, so it is a matter of balancing future flexibility with lower maintainability.

Comment: unfortunately, the question asked about Ajax request, so the server must be the same as the where the page was loaded from. The acknowledged way to do what you suggest is with a load balancer in front of multiple servers, all serving the same content (i.e. all have the same servlets)

Answer (score 1):

There is as such no performance enhancements in case you use multiple servlets since for each servlet request is handled in a separate thread, provided it is not single threaded.

But keeping modularity and separation of code, you can have multiple servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tony said, there really isn't a reason to use more than one servlet, unless you need to break up a complex Java Servlet class or perhaps implement an intercepting filter.

Comment: 1. You should rarely, if ever, add attributes to ServletContext.
2. Can you back this up: "Multiple servlets is definitely the way to go for raw speed"? it is simply not correct,If you need to synchronize on something, you will have to synchronize whether you have 1 or 100 servlets

Comment: 1. Just saying ServletContext is not thread-safe and nothing about good practice. 2. You're absolutely right on that, brain fart on my part and I'll change my answer. I was thinking that we might avoid thread blocking in some small way with multiple servlets. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know that you can have multiple instances of the same servlet as long as you register different  nodes in the web.xml file for your app -- ie, assuming you want to do that.

Other than that, from what I'm understanding, you might benefit from comet architecture -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming). 
There are already some implementations of Comet on some servlet containers -- here's one look at how to use Ajax and Comet -- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jettydwr/. You should study before deciding on your architecture.

BR,
~A